# How to hydrate Project name in SnapshotStore

Tags: javascript, rally

When using the SnapshotStore, I have been unable to hydrate the "Name" property of the objects that are returning as part of my query.  I get the correct OID for the project, but I would like to display the string name of the project instead of the OID.  How can I go about doing that?

This is the code that I am using to query, but when I add the "Project" property to the Hydrate field, it does not seem to matter.  If I comment out the hydrate line entirely, the state and resolution come back as unhydrated and not readable (by most people) so I know that it is at least working.

```
doSearch: function(query, fields, sort, pageSize, callback){
    var transformStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
        context: {
            workspace: this.context.getWorkspace(),
             project: this.context.getProject()
        },
        fetch: fields,
        find: query,
        autoLoad: true,
    hydrate: ["State","Resolution","Project"],
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            load: this.processSnapshots
        }
    });
},
```

"We could not find the user-friendly form for the following: 'Project':7579240995" - is what I get when trying to include "Project" in the hydrate field.

I read somewhere that hydrate only works with drop down menus.  Is that correct?  And if so, how would I be able to show the project name easily for each object that the query is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Project is not a hydratable field.  In general the fields that can be hydrated are dropdown fields as you mentioned in your question.

The best way to do what you need is to use a Rally.data.WsapiDataStore to query for the projects in your current workspace and to build an in-memory map of OID to name.

```
var projects = {};
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model: 'Project',
    autoLoad: true,
    limit: Infinity,
    fetch: ['Name', 'ObjectID'],
    context: this.getContext().getDataContext(),
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records) {
            Ext.Array.each(records, function(record) {
                projects[record.get('ObjectID')] = record.get('Name');
            });
        }
    }
});
```